# How to find the targets that a helm-configured prometheus blackbox exporter container is scraping

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I'm using someone else's helm release of blackbox exporter that is configured to scrape a bunch of endpoints and it seemed to be doing so correctly. I'm planning to add different endpoints but I've noticed that, out of the templates in my working directory (for configuring the custom endpoints in the helm release), **there are only 4**... and yet the exporter is successfully scraping metrics from **6** endpoints.

To investigate this inconsistency further, I am wondering **how to inspect the running blackbox-exporter instances's configuration—specifically which endpoints are being probed—while exec'd into / in a sh shell inside the blackbox container**. I'm able to find some related files and see the blackbox process running with a `ps -a`, but cannot seem to investigate its config as it's running.

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Blackbox Exporter but, it would be helpful to include the Helm Chart's `values.yaml` and the relevant template file (it's name should help identify it) in your question. You can try `helm template`'ing the Chart and grep'ing the results to see what's being applied to the cluster too. The most relevant file is likely `prometheus.yml` which should include the configuration that's being passed to the prober.

Answer (score 0):

Each blackbox exporter instance has a web UI you can check that will have a history of what URLs it probed and the result.

Example using docker to run locally:

```
docker run -p 9115:9115 prom/blackbox-exporter
```

Then I can visit `localhost:9115` to see a simple UI where you can manually scrape targets via query params but also more importantly a list of recent probes:

[image]